# Does speech to text happens on device?

Tags: android, voice, speech-to-text

(I do not have any dev android phone and currently working on emulator only. As the emulator do not have voice input method,  these silly question came up in my mind.)

Does android process speech input on the device itsself (with limited computing power of 300-500MHz or 1 GHz) or it sends to Google Serves and gets text back?

- Does it work when off-line?
- How long speech input can be processed at a time without any break?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the actual speech to text is done on Google's servers, your phone just records the data and sends it to them. It does not work when offline.

Comment: thanks. i also found on android blog http://android-developers.blogspot.com/search/label/Speech%20Input . they stream recording to google servers.